# Cannot pin from Zapier

Tags: google-sheets, pinterest, zapier

I am using Zapier to send a pin to my Pinterest account from Google Sheets 
but it is showing me an error:

> We had trouble sending your test through. The app returned "Sorry! We
>   blocked this link because it may lead to spam.". It looks like the
>   server for your connected app is down or currently experiencing
>   problems. Please check the app's status page or contact support if
>   there are no reported issues.

[My Sample Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9KML.png)

[image: My Sample Record]

[My sample Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOuGi.png)

[image: My sample Excel File]

[My Board Link where I want to pin](https://bestboxinggloves.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not already reached out to them, I would suggest that this is the perfect question for Zapier's support team. They are quite punctual and have access to information regarding specific app integration status' that we, the general public, will not. That said this looks like it may be a symptom of an error with Zapier's Google Sheet integration. At the time of this writing Zapier is reporting 429 errors concerning Google Sheets. If I am ever facing unexplained errors with one of my zaps the first place I check is https://status.zapier.com/ which has live updates and reports on any integrations that may be facing issues.